# Very strange plot from basic ASCII file data

Tags: python, matplotlib

Working with Jupyter Lab!

I loaded a simple ASCII file (as I've done 100s of times before...), with three columns and 2000+ lines. I did it with

```py
with open(file) as f: 
    d = f.readlines()
```

and also with NumPy `d = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter=',')` to see if something would change.

All values in the 2nd column (Latitude) are -32. and something and all values in the 3rd column (Longitude) are -52. and something. However, de variation of the data is about the 5th decimal number... (I think this is making things weird!)

When I printed the data on the screen, it seems ok! But when I try to plot them, I got pretty weird stuff... the numbers in the X and Y axis are nonsense, especially the one scaling the x-axis. `1e-5-5.2103e1`

I open the data in a spreadsheet (Libre Calc), and there the plot seems alright. Then I save it with another name and tried to load in the Jupyter again and got the same weird result.

I also tried it also using a different computer... same result!

Tried a script using Atom... same result!

Can someone give a clue about what is going on?

The file is shared at:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eDwlijQ7y3KoIRafoE00eqK3UYsIcMvf/view?usp=sharing

First lines o the file...

```
9738,-32.13689233,-52.10339483
9739,-32.13689233,-52.10339483
9740,-32.13689233,-52.10339483
9741,-32.13689233,-52.10339483
9742,-32.13689233,-52.10339483
9743,-32.13689233,-52.10339483
9744,-32.13689233,-52.10339483
9745,-32.13689233,-52.10339483
9746,-32.13689233,-52.10339483
9747,-32.13689233,-52.10339483
9748,-32.13689233,-52.10339483
9749,-32.13689433,-52.10339417
9750,-32.13689433,-52.10339417
9751,-32.13689433,-52.10339417
9752,-32.13689433,-52.10339417
9753,-32.13689433,-52.10339417
9754,-32.13689433,-52.10339417
9755,-32.13689433,-52.10339417
9756,-32.13689433,-52.10339417
9757,-32.13689433,-52.10339417
9758,-32.13689433,-52.10339417
9759,-32.13688733,-52.10339367
```

[image]

Comment: The plot seems fine, I guess the source of confusion is the scientific notation used with the tick labels. On the x-axis `1e-5-5.2103e1` means that the value each label should be multiplied by 10^(-5), and then -5.210*10^1 should be added to the result. In this way -42 becomes -52.10042 etc. The formatting of tick labels can be changed if needed, see [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html).

Comment: Indeed... the plot is fine! I got confused with the tick labels... I realized that when I start playing with the x and y limits! Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your plot is correct, even though the scaling of the axes is quite strange (likely due to the very small range). I plotted the same data using Altair, which was able to handle the axes ranges much better:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
with open("lat_long.csv", newline="") as f:
    frame = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=",", header=None, names=["index", "longitude", "latitude"])

alt.Chart(frame).mark_circle(size=10).encode(
    alt.X('latitude',
        scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)
    ),
    alt.Y('longitude',
        scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)
    ),
).interactive()
```

The result matches yours, except for the more sensible axes:
[image]

My guess is that the pandas plotter is just doing something strange with displaying the axes, but the data is being read in correctly.

Comment: Thanks... nice readable tick labels! I was expecting to get something like that from the start! Need to consider alternatives for 'matploblib'...

Answer (score 0):

This is how matplotlib displays very large and small tick markers. For example, to read the y-axis you take that number at the top and add each tick marker. I'll admit, the number on the x-axis is weird, but you can see a recognizable prefix in there: -5.2103e1. The 1e-5 might just be signifying the decimal place the ticks start at. Looking through the file, the plot makes sense, and the labels do as well.

Comment: Yes... now I know after reading the answers and comments... but when you are exploring some unfamiliar data, this weird notation doesn't help at all... should be improved!